# JavaScript Variable List and Editor

Tags: javascript, firefox, variables, firefox-addon, mozilla

I am looking for an extension for Firefox that will list all JavaScript variables on a page, along with their values, and will allow you to edit them so that their values are different. If there is a way to do this, whether it be with or without an add-on, please tell me so.

Thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try firebug, it is a very nice tool, you can debug the javascript and output all the variables in scope.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firebug/

https://getfirebug.com/downloads

[image]

Comment: How convenient! I have Firebug, but I haven't been able to find the list that I am talking about.

Comment: in order to get the list you need and see the javascript variables value, you should stop the script somewhere (then you can see the in-scope variables)

Comment: all what you need is to click on the left side window on one of the lines (line number on the left) you will see a red circle that means your javascript will stop there, once there you will see the list of variable in the the 'watch' tab.